# How do I assert that an async task should complete within a minimum and maximum time?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I can assert that a task should complete within a specified maximum time like this:

```
await obj.Awaiting( o => o.DoSomethingAsync() ).Should().CompleteWithinAsync( 1.Second() );
```

But how can I also require that the task also takes *at least* a certain amount of time to complete? For example, I want to assert that the task should take between 1 and 2 seconds to complete, such that taking less than 1 second or more than 2 seconds indicates failure?

I'm aware of `NotCompleteWithinAsync`, but I can't work out how to combine both `CompleteWithinAsync` and `NotCompleteWithinAsync` in one assertion.

Comment: You mean NotCompleteWithinAsync https://fluentassertions.com/specialized/ ?

Comment: Ah yes, I did see that, but I could not work out how to combine both `CompleteWithinAsync` and `NotCompleteWithinAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ExecutionTime` extension method and combine it with `BeCloseTo`. Something like

```
Awaiting(() => DoSomethingAsync()).ExecutionTime().Should().BeCloseTo(1.Minutes(), 5.Seconds());
```